# Write dataframe from spark cluster to cassandra cluster: Partitioning and Performance Tuning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I have two clusters - 
1. Cloudera Hadoop- Spark jobs run here
2. Cloud - Cassandra cluster, multiple DC

While writing a dataframe from my spark job to a cassandra cluster, I am doing a repartition (repartionCount=10) in spark before writing. See below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
records.repartition(repartitionCount).write.cassandraFormat(table, keySpace)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .options(options)
  .option(CassandraConnectorConf.LocalDCParam.name, cassandraDC.name)
  .option(CassandraConnectorConf.ConnectionHostParam.name, cassandraDC.hosts)
  .save()
```

In my multi tenant spark cluster, for a spark batch load with 20M records, and below configs, I see lot of task failures, resource preemption and on the fly failures.

```
spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.buffer.size=1000
spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key=partition
spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes=20 
spark.cassandra.connection.compression=LZ4
```

How should I tune this? Is the repartition to blame?

PS: My understanding in the beginning was: For a load with 20M rows, the "repartition" should distribute load evenly over executors (partition with 2M rows each), and batching will be done on these partition level (on 2M rows). But now, I am doubting is this causing unnecessary shuffle, if the spark-cassandra-connector is doing batching on whole dataframe level (whole 20M rows).

UPDATE: Removing the "repartition" brought down the performance a lot on my cloudera spark cluster (default partitions set at spark level is - `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: 200`), so i dug a bit deeper and found my initial understanding was correct. Please note my spark and cassandra clusters are different. Datastax spark-cassandra-connector opens one connection per partition with a cassandra coordinator node, so I have decided to let it be the same. As Alex suggested, I have reduced the concurrent writes, I believe that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do repartition in Spark - just write data from Spark to Cassandra, don't try to change Spark Cassandra Connector defaults - they are work fine in the most situations.  You need to look what kind of stage failures happening - most probably you're simply overloading Cassandra because of `spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes=20` (use default value (`5`)) - sometimes having less writers help to write data faster as you don't overload Cassandra, and jobs aren't restarted.

P.S. `partition` in the `spark.cassandra.output.batch.grouping.key` - it's not a Spark partition, it's Cassandra partition that depends on the value of partition key column.

Comment: Thank you so much. There is a bunch of thing going wrong in my cluster with increasing number of batch jobs writing to cassandra cluster parallely. Each batch jobs even though huge, has a high cardinality, where a single partition (cassandra) can frequently be less than 1000 rows, thus batches might be smaller at runtime causing more write requests to cassandra. Also, I observed on rare occasion that cassandra read goes down during heavy write, although write itself is always pretty fast. Is replica_set a good option in my scenario, along with above suggestions.

Comment: If your Cassandra nodes going down frequently during read, you may need to tune input parameters. For example, reading with `LOCAL_ONE` often overloads the node, while reading with `LOCAL_QUORUM` puts less load onto individual node, and because it doesn't crash, it reads faster although `LOCAL_QUORUM` is slower than `LOCAL_ONE`

Comment: We write with EACH_QUORUM, read with LOCAL_QUORUM. Cassandra not was not down but read latency increased many folds during heavy write.

Comment: that's expected, but the main thing is that your nodes are not down